# Optimizing algorithm to lessen time complexity (redis data types used)

Tags: algorithm, redis

**Background:**

In my website, users are creating their social network. This causes notifications to fly to related nodes in the network. E.g. friend requests, likes, comments, all generate a notification for relevant nodes in the network.

To keep everything transparent, users can view their relevant notifications as a list in a separate url. This list is powered by a redis-backed sorted set called `ss:<user_id>`. The sorted set contains `hash ids`, along with time since epoch (as the `score`). For e.g.:

```
hash_id              |     updated_at
np:1:0:544           |     1482234321.48124
np:1:2:454           |     1482235629.73111
np:1:1:701           |     1482237000.59143
```

Also, each notification is either **seen** or **unseen**. This `seen` state is stored in the relevant hash, at key `s`. E.g. the `s` key in hash `np:1:0:544` is `False`; telling us it's an unseen notification. Simple enough.

---

**The challenge:**

The challenge is to count all **unseen notifications** beyond a pre-defined epoch time. This time is stored in a separate counter called `cut-off`.

---

**What I'm already doing:**

1) Get all hash_ids from `ss:<user_id>` with scores higher than `cut-off`. E.g. `ZRANGEBYSCORE ss:<user_id> (cut-off +inf` (in redis parlance).

2) Loop through each hash_id, checking it's `s` key (i.e. `seen` key). If `s` is `False`, increment a counter. E.g. do `HGET hash_name s` for every hash object. If returned value is `False`, `incr` a separate redis counter.

The time complexity of step 1 is `O(log(N)+M)`. That of step 2 is `O(M)`. It could be `O(N)` at max.

---

**What I need to improve:**

Is there any way I can do this in lesser time complexity (e.g. `O(log(N)`)? E.g. by using composite indexing and lexicographical ordering?

Performance is critical; this calculation happens ~2 million times daily on my website (and scaling up), so I'm looking for ways to improve scalability.

---

*Note: there are of course other measures I can take to lessen the load of this algo (e.g. reduce its incidence, improve infrastructure etc.), but those are a different consideration.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my approach.

The `score` (i.e. `updated_at`) of the sorted set is now `time.time()+SEEN[status]` where `SEEN={True:2000000000,False:4000000000}`. This automatically sorts the keys by **seen** and **unseen**, while preserving time information as well (gotten by `score-SEEN[status]`).

Overall, this approach has enabled me to cut out step 2 from the calculation. Time complexity is down to O(log(N)). The big take away is that intelligent formulation of the index can really drive performance. For anyone interested, [here's an informative read](https://redis.io/topics/indexes) about how sophisticated indexing can accomplish various things.